# Move multiple files by the date in file name into month named folders using a batch file script

Tags: batch-file, files-folders, file-organization

```
@ECHO ON

SET "Src=H:\Trial\Testing"
SET "Dest=H:\Trial\Testing"

FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=1 DELIMS=- " %%A IN (`DIR /B "%Src%\*.pdf"`) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%%~A" MD "%%~A"
    XCOPY /F /Y "%Src%\*%%~A*.pdf" "%Dest%\%%~A\" && DEL /Q /F "%Src%\*%%~A*.pdf"
    )

EXIT
```

Trying to use a batch file to do this with the above script. Need your assistance to edit it to match my date format

I have 2 folders with over 180,000 pdf files in each with the format 2022-11-21_TestP_NEG

So all the file names start with yyyy-mm-dd_filename.

- In the first one I want to move them into the month-wise folder.
- In the second one I want to move them month-wise with a separate date-wise folder within each month.

Comment: Is this one time or continuously

Comment: It is a one time task

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: You can just use file explorer itself.  Just type in a wildcard (as an example, you have to try it **-11-**.pdf), select the files, and move them.  Often, it's faster just you use brute force.

Comment: Questions involving data in filenames are very good and I like to try to answer and see other proposed answers, I hope it reopens, good luck!

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean with that: "separate date-wise folder within each month."

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly where the month part should be it is easy, just extract from the sixth to seventh character of the filename and save it in a variable, next check if such a folder already exist in the destination and if not create it. Then move the file to the destination\!Month! variable.

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set Src=Source
set Dest=Source

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%Src%\*.pdf"') do (
                                                     set Name=%%a
                                                     set Month=!Name:~5,2!
                                                     if not exist "%Dest%\!Month!" md "%Dest%\!Month!"
                                                     move "%Src%\!Name!" "%Dest%\!Month!"
                                                    )
```

[image]